# email does not go through if it contains a url - classic ASP

Tags: email, asp-classic

We have a catalog type website hosted on godaddy.com developed in classic asp. Very basic and no bells and whistles. Amongst other functions we have a small bit of code used to recommend an item in the catalog to a friend which is fairly straight forward.

This function has suddenly stopped working and email recommendations do not go out even though no code changes have been done. Also no error message or emails bouncing back!

No progress with godaddy support but now have been able to identify the problem and it seems that it is the embedded url/link in the email msg body causing it to fail.

Any ideas on how I can bypass any restrictions or resolve this issue?

thanks!

```
Dim objNewMail, sBody

Set objNewMail = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")
objNewMail.From = Request.Form("Your email address")
objNewMail.Cc = Request.Form("Your email address")
objNewMail.To   = Request.Form("Email to")
objNewMail.Subject = "Interesting property sent by " & Trim(Request.Form("Your name"))

sBody = Trim(Request.Form("Your name")) & " wants to show you an interesting property listed by " & vbcr & vbcr
sBody = sBody & "Example Properties Ltd, Malta" & vbcr & vbcr
sBody = sBody & "Click the following link to see the property :" & vbcr & vbcr & "http://www.example.com/default.asp?pid=" & Request.Form("pid")

If Request.Form("Message") <> "" Then
    sBody = sBody & vbcr & vbcr & "Message from : " & Request.Form("Your Name") & vbcr & vbcr & Request.Form("Message")
End If
objNewMail.TextBody = sBody

' GoDaddy SMTP Settings
objNewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing")=2
objNewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver")="relay-hosting.secureserver.net"
objNewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport")=25 
objNewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60
objNewMail.Configuration.Fields.Update
objNewMail.Send

'After the Send method, NewMail Object become Invalid
Set objNewMail = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the problem was not with the code or the url in the email msg body but the particular website mentioned in the url which must have somehow ended up on some blacklist! Sorry for the false alarm and leaving this in here in case it is useful for someone else.